# Validation for all <tr> by checkbox not working

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a checkbox in the first `<td>`, now I want to check only those `<tr>` where the check boxes are checked.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th style="width: 5%;">Select</th>
    <th style="width: 5%;">ID</th>
    <th style="width: 10%;">Name</th>
    <th style="width: 5%;">Order</th>
    <th style="width: 5%;">Price</th>

</tr>
<c:forEach var="pack" items="${PackList}" varStatus="rowCounter">
    <tr class="allPackClass">
        <td class="selective_CatCreation"><input type="checkbox" name="packIdCatCreate" value="${pack.packId}"></td>
        <td>${pack.packId}</td>
        <td>${pack.name}</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="packDisOrder" disabled="disabled" style="width: 20px;" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="packPrice" disabled="disabled" style="width: 20px;" value=""></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

validation -->

```
$("tr.allPackClass").each(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")== true){
            if($(this).closest('tr').find('input:text').val() == ""){
                $("#validationDiv_").html("<span style='font-size:12px;color:red;'>Fileds are missing</span>");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Please help, where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` condition is not working because inside the `each` loop `this` is referencing the `tr` element, not the `checkbox` inside it

change the tr filter so that it fetches only those trs with checked check boxes and then remove the `if` condition inside it

```
$("tr.allPackClass").has('input[name="packIdCatCreate"]:checked').each(function() {
```

ex

```
$("tr.allPackClass").has('input[name="packIdCatCreate"]:checked').each(function() {
    var $emtpy = $(this).find('input:text').filter(function() {
                return $.trim(this.value).length == 0;
            });
    if ($emtpy.length) {
        $("#validationDiv_")
                .html("<span style='font-size:12px;color:red;'>Fileds are missing</span>");
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Update**:

```
var valid = $("tr.allPackClass").has('input[name="packIdCatCreate"]:checked').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('input:text').filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value).length == 0;
    }).length > 0;
}).length == 0;
if (!valid) {
    $("#validationDiv_").html("<span style='font-size:12px;color:red;'>Fileds are missing</span>");
    return false;
}}
```

Comment: He has two input:text in one tr.

Comment: Thanks , its working , but not returning flase or breaking the loop when the validation falied

Comment: @– Arun P Johny  . Thanks, its all ok now

Answer (score 0):

@dude you have an error here

```
if($(this).is(":checked")== true)
```

Should be like

```
if($(this).find('[name=packIdCatCreate]').is(":checked")== true)
```

rest should work,

have not gone through though